# android place a view in a specific place above an image

Tags: android, xml, image, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to create a layout that contains an image on top of which I want to place many images and TextViews. I know how to place images on top of one another using RelativeLayout, but how to align them in a desired way? Eg I want an image to be exactly in a place where my “background” image has a specific black circle. Playing with values like android:layout_marginTop etc does not seem to do the effect in every screen.

So which is the proper way to handle these issues?

EDIT:
I cannot upload the images, but I uploaded a very simple sketch of what I want here:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/715/buttonlayout.png/
all the buttons have also Icons and text (which must be a textview so that I can change it programmatically if need be)

Comment: can you provide the "background” image

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a custom layout that places the image specifically where you want them relative to the size of the parent view. If you choose, you can override the `LayoutParams` and apply custom attributes to them for your custom view to read.

Anyway, to specifically place an item, say 30% down from the top and 20% from the left, you would overwrite `onLayout()`.

```
@Override
public void onLayout(boolean c, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(c, left, top, right, bottom);

    int width = right - left;
    int height = bottom - top;

    View v = getTheChildView();
    int viewL = left + (int)(width * .2f); // The left pixel is 20% down the total width of the parent view
    int viewR = viewL + v.getWidth(); // The right pixel is the left pixel plus the measured width of the child view itself
    int viewT = top + (int)(height * .3f); // The top pixel is 30% down the total height of the parent view
    int viewB = top + v.getHeight(); // The bottom pixel is the top pixel plus the measured height of the child view itself   
    v.layout(viewL, viewT, viewR, viewB);
}
```

Comment: This seems promising thank you. You mean to implement this custom layout as a class that extends layout, and pass this class to my xml elements?

Comment: You can override any layout implementation if you want to use the specific elements of it.  For example, you may want to override `RelativeLayout` if you want other `Views` to use the specific `RelativeLayout` attributes like `alignParentLeft`.  If the view is defined in xml, then the children should already be there upon inflation of the layout.  You just need a system on retrieving it (the `getTheChildView()` method).